# Can an equation represent a curve in 3D space?

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions

I tried to get a equation that can represent a spiral like spring:

$$z=\frac{height}{2\pi }\cdot \arctan \left ( \sqrt{\frac{radius^{2}-x^{2}}{radius^{2}-y^{2}}} \right )$$

I am **not sure** about the equation I got, so I am confused about...

- whether this equation really represent a spiral like spring?
- whether an equation can represent a curve or a line in 3D space?
- whether any other equation can also represent a curve or a line in 3D space?

Comment: Here's [the surface your equation actually represents](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20z%20=%201/%282%20pi%29%20arctan%28sqrt%28%281%20-%20x%5E2%29/%281%20-%20y%5E2%29%29%29%20for%20x=-1..1,%20y=-1..1). :) The Wikipedia page Amzoti first linked to has the equations you want that represent a helix. But they are [a different sort of representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation) than something like $z = f(x,y)$, which represents a surface, not a curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that a curve $\gamma$ can be parametrized in the form
$$\gamma:\quad z\mapsto\bigl(f(z),g(z),z\bigr)\qquad(-\infty<z<\infty)$$
with two functions $f$ and $g$. Then the curve $\gamma$ as a point set can be defined by a single equation as follows:
$$\bigl\{(x,y,z)\in{\mathbb R}^3\ \bigm|\ \bigl(x-f(z)\bigr)^2+(y-g(z)\bigr)^2 =0\bigr\}\ .$$
But *this is highly artificial*. E.g., you will not be able to compute tangent directions, length, etc., from this representation of $\gamma$.

"Generically" $r$ equations involving $n$ variables define a submanifold $M\subset{\mathbb R}^n$ of dimension $d=n-r$. A single equation, say $$\cos(x+y)- z\sin(x-y)-4=0\ ,$$
defines a two-dimensional surface $S\subset{\mathbb R}^3$. But only a careful analysis of this equation will reveal whether $S$ is actually a bona fide surface, or whether singularities are present.