# Why 2 equations of the form F(x,y,z) = 0 for one 3D curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, 3d, curves

It says in my analysis 2 book that a curve is given by $F_1(x,y,z) = 0$ and $F_2(x,y,z) = 0$. Why do we need two equations of $x,y,z$ To define a curve in 3D, shouldn't one be enough?

Comment: Each function defines a surface. The system of two functions defines the intersection of both surfaces, i. e. a curve.

Comment: I read http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806048/can-an-equation-represent-a-curve-in-3d-space so i thought that one was enough.. But it seems resonable that two surfaces intersect to give a curve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

One equation gives you a surface   : $$x^2+y^2+z^2-2=0 \tag{1}$$

is a sphere

Imagine another surface intersecting this sphere, for example, a plane :
$$z +2=0\tag{2}$$

Solving both gives you a **circle** :

[image]

Comment: Beautiful picture: +1

Comment: Minor quibble: The first equation gives you a sphere of radius $\sqrt 2$ which doesn't intersect with the plane $z = -2$?